# Variant with unique types

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

While writing a cpp library I ended up with possiblity that `std::variant`s shall contain repeating types, that is for example, `std::variant<int, double, int, std::string, int>`. It may be useful in some occasions but in case of my library I find this unnecessary. And so I would like to filter type reptitions like this:

`std::variant<int, double, int, std::string, int>` -> `std::variant<int, double, std::string>`

`std::variant<std::string, std::string, int>` -> `std::variant<std::string, int>`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct filter_duplicates { using type = T; };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename... Ts, typename U, typename... Us>
struct filter_duplicates<C<Ts...>, U, Us...>
    : std::conditional_t<(std::is_same_v<U, Ts> || ...)
                       , filter_duplicates<C<Ts...>, Us...>
                       , filter_duplicates<C<Ts..., U>, Us...>> {};

template <typename T>
struct unique_variant;

template <typename... Ts>
struct unique_variant<std::variant<Ts...>> : filter_duplicates<std::variant<>, Ts...> {};

template <typename T>
using unique_variant_t = typename unique_variant<T>::type;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4a95f8f0371780a)

Answer (score 5):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_uniquel), this is a short one-liner (as always):

```
using V1 = mp_unique<std::variant<int, double, int, std::string, int>>;
// V1 is std::variant<int, double, std::string>

using V2 = mp_unique<std::variant<std::string, std::string, int>>;
// V2 is std::variant<std::string, int>
```

Comment: I love how simple it is but I'll wait for something non-boost. I don't want to pull that big dependency into small project

Comment: @bartop It's a standalone library.

Answer (score 0):

My own version using C++11 (non-boost):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct contains : std::integral_constant<bool, false> {};
template <typename T, typename T2, typename... Args>
struct contains<T, T2, Args...> : contains<T, Args...> {};
template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct contains<T, T, Args...> : std::integral_constant<bool, true> {};
template <typename W, typename... Ts>
struct __make_unique_impl {
  using type = W;
};
template <template <typename...> class W, typename... Current, typename T,
          typename... Ts>
struct __make_unique_impl<W<Current...>, T, Ts...>
    : std::conditional<
          contains<T, Ts...>::value,
          typename __make_unique_impl<W<Current...>, Ts...>::type,
          typename __make_unique_impl<W<Current..., T>, Ts...>::type> {};
template <typename W>
struct make_unique;
template <template <typename...> class W, typename... T>
struct make_unique<W<T...>> : __make_unique_impl<W<>, T...> {};
```

How to use:

```cpp
#include <variant>
using test_t = typename make_unique<std::variant<int, std::string, std::string, int>>::type; // std::variant<int, std::string>
```